# How to disallow a drawable alias to increase the container size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have a layout with a LinearLayout root that has an [XML drawable alias](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) as it's background. The container has a huge additional padding on the bottom edge that goes away once i remove the android:background tag. How can i prevent/remove this annoying behaviour?

XML Drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<bitmap
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:src="@drawable/BackgroundImage"
  android:gravity="fill" />
```

I have tried a couple of gravity values but they all generate that hideous padding on the bottom edge of the container for no reason at all.

The effect that i want to achieve is to have the src file be stretched in height to match the container (**match**, with no additional space) and rendered with a proportional width.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a drawable like that, you should put your drawable into folders like drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi etc. and resize them according to dpi.

For example:

- drawable-mdpi -> 48x48 px
- drawable-hdpi -> 72x72 px
- drawable-xdpi ->96x96 px

If you want to stretch your drawable, you should consider to use 9patch.